# storing data from service.ts to use in the same service.ts

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have firestore.service.ts, and in a method I create and update a collection in firebase ... after leaving the method, I change the "id" of the collections, but I NEED that this "id" is not lost because I need it to the next method.
How can I preserve this "id" value?

```
  public createFormulario ( data ) {
        return this.firestore.collection('formularios').add(data).then
        (ref => {
          data.id = ref.id; <==keep this data.id
         this.firestore.collection('formularios').doc( ref.id ).update(data);
        });

  public createPregunta1 ( data: any ) {

    this.firestore.collection('formularios').doc( 'i need the above data.id here' ).update(data);
}
```

so, i need the capture data.id from the createFormulario...
and use it in other method called createPregunta1.

obviously when the app run and pass from the first page to the second one. that data.id gets null

Comment: You can declare a variable in your service/class for example id: number; and then in your createFormulario method you can say this.id = ref.id; This will store it globally in the service and you can reference it in the createPreguntal method as this.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a variable in your service/class for example `id: number;` This can then be referenced anywhere in your class.

So in your `createFormulario` method you can say `this.id = ref.id;` This will store the id globally (within the service) and you can reference it in the `createPreguntal` method as `this.id`.

```
export class FirestoreService {
  //declare our class variables
  id: number;

  public createFormulario ( data ) {
      return this.firestore.collection('formularios').add(data).then
          (ref => {
            this.id = ref.id; //store the id in our class variable
            this.firestore.collection('formularios').doc( ref.id ).update(data);
          });
  }

  public createPregunta1 ( data: any ) {
      this.firestore.collection('formularios').doc(this.id).update(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes!!! that is the correct answer.
but instead of using number.... i use string

thanks a lot. that it the spot

Comment: @SergioJoséVillalobosAguilar Thats great, no probs :)

Comment: @SergioJoséVillalobosAguilar Glad to have helped. If you believe this is what you needed, feel free to mark is as the answer. (There's a tick to left side of the question.) Thanks :)